# WPF Library: fonts not visible at design time in Visual Studio

Tags: wpf, shared-libraries, resourcedictionary

I have a library project for my UI controls and styles which I reuse in my WPF applications. Some of the styles are using a specific icon font (Segoe MDL2 Assets). When I use these styles in the WPF application, it'll display the icon font perfectly when running the app. 
However, design time, in Visual Studio, the icon font is not used and is just displayed as missing symbol.

I reference the style using a StaticResource and reference the library using a ResourceDictionary.

How can I fix that?

Comment: using fonts as icons is a bad idea as you cannot make sure they will be present on the machine your application will run on...You should use Paths instead and make your icon in XAML! or (but this is a bad approach) use bitmap images

Comment: We ship the icon files along to cover that one.

Comment: Is your application 64-bit only? If so, that is probably the cause. Visual Studio is 32-bit so the designer can only load 32-bit/any cpu DLLs. I recently had this happen to me when I switch a client's application to 64-bit only. If I switch it to any cpu the designer works again.

Comment: Both the library and the application projects are set to build on Any CPU - so unfortunately that's not the solution.